# Different object and reference

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

I was trying to learn Java from Tutorials Point. So, may be this question would be so basic. But I am really stuck here. And I don't know what to google to get it resolved.

Please have a look at this program.

```
class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
}

public class TestDog{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); 
      Animal b = new Dog(); 

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class

      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class
   }
}
```

Please have a look at the object creation.

```
Animal a = new Animal(); 
Animal b = new Dog();
```

What is the difference between these two? I am familiar with the first one. Could someone explain in simple terms what happens when an object is defined in the second way?

Comment: The first creates a new `Animal`, the second creates a new `Dog`.

Comment: `Dog` is a kind of `Animal`

Comment: I know that sounds weird, but Google: "Java animal dog".

Comment: Refer to java docs, it can help sometimes and gives to you details of inheritance. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Animal a = new Animal();` --> creates an instance of `Animal` referenced as an `Animal`. Only `Animal` methods will be available to invoke from `a`.
- `Animal b = new Dog();` --> since `Dog` extends `Animal`, creates an instance of `Dog` referenced as an `Animal`. Only `Animal` methods (i.e. no methods pertaining only to `Dog`) will be available to invoke from `b`, but the virtual method invocation mechanism will resolve method invocation to `Dog`'s implementations at runtime, when overriding `Animal`'s.

**Note**

`Object` methods (`equals`, `hashCode`, `wait` overloads, `notify`, `notifyAll`, `toString` and `getClass`) are available to all objects.

**Fully commented example**

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Abstract class - using anonymous idiom here
         * Can invoke:
         * move
         * forAnimalAndChildren
         * all Object methods
         */
        Animal animal = new Animal(){}; 
        /*
         * Instance type is Dog but reference is Animal
         * Can invoke:
         * move
         * forAnimalAndChildren
         * all Object methods
         * Note that invoking "move" will 
         * resolve to Dog's "move" implementation at runtime, 
         * if any is provided in class Dog
         */
        Animal dogReferencedAsAnimal = new Dog();
        /*
         * Instance and reference types are Dog
         * Can invoke:
         * move
         * forAnimalAndChildren
         * onlyDog
         * all Object methods
         */
        Dog dog = new Dog();

    }
    /*
     * Setting this up as an abstract class, as no concrete "animals" can exist - only more specific types. 
     */
    static abstract class Animal {
        void move() {
            System.out.println("Animal moving...");
        }
        void forAnimalAndChildren() {
            System.out.println("Anyone extending Animal can invoke me!");
        }
    }
    static class Dog extends Animal {
        @Override
        void move() {
            System.out.println("Dog moving...");
        }
        void onlyDog() {
            System.out.println("Only for dogs!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, So... If I create the second Object as ``Dog b = new Dog();`` then calling ``b.move();`` will return the same result ``"Dogs can walk and run"`` but that Object cannot use the methods in class ``Animal``. Am I correct?

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus not quite. `b.move()` will always resolve to `Dog`'s `move` implementation if invoked from an instance of `Dog` (so you are correct there), but since `Dog` extends `Animal`, if the reference is `Dog`, you can still invoke any `Animal` method (just like since all objects implicitly extend `Object`, you can invoke any `Object` method).

Answer (score 1):

`Dog` class inherits from `Animal` class.

In the example above, the first creates and `Animal` object while the second creates a `Dog` object. But because the `Dog` class inherits from the `Animal` class, the `move()` function in `Dog` overrides the `move()` function in `Animal` (since they are they have the same function prototype).

Thus, when you run the `b.move()`, you run the `Dog`'s `move()` function instead.

Comment: What if it were created as ``Dog b = new Dog();``? Does it mean that the object cannot use methods of animal class at all? Or is there any other siginifcant difference?

Comment: since `b` is now a `Dog`, the `move()` method will still be the `Dog` one. Since `Dog` inherits from `Animal`, it could still use `Animal` methods.